# Rails endpoint performance - what to look for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Ruby on Rails 5 API only app and I'm running into serious performance issues on one endpoint. I already investigated the Postgres performance and the queries only take a few milliseconds according to Heroku Postgres Diagnose tool. That's not perfect, but the http request from Postman or any frontend takes 5-20 seconds.

The table contains round about 500.000 rows.

The methods included simply join tables, they are connected through non-ActiveRecord ids. There are indexes on all these tables/ids.

I tested with removing each include and each method and removing all methods and all includes at all. Every removed item improves performance a small increment, but the overall performance stays bad.

I believe there will be an issue not directly related to slow SQL or PG performance, but I'm blind here. Do you have a good idea what to test?

```
def index
...
  alarms = Alarm.where(company_id: @company.id, state: 
 @states).by_prio.limit(@per_page).offset(@page * @per_page).as_json(
  only: %i[id state created_at updated_at],
  include: [:client, :notes, { delegations: { include: [:alarm_delegation] } }],
  methods: %i[zones phones memos priority type cluster]
  )

  render json: {
    alarms: alarms,
    page: @page,
    items: alarms.size,
    total: @items
  }

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  head :not_found
end
```

Comment: "...the http request from Postman or any frontend takes 5-20 seconds.", if you already checked your query(ies) and know that the average time isn't those 5-20 seconds, then there's the hint on what to do next. You mention an external HTTP request responds with that delay, so it might worth discarding that part.

Comment: Have you looked at the rails logs? Usually it offers some insight into x time spent in AR, y time spent rendering the view, and z total time.

Comment: All other endpoints on that API respond within a few milliseconds. Only that Index method takes this long time, no matter if called from the frontend or Postman.